# get the difference between a file in a git repo for a specific commit and a file outside the repo

Tags: git, github

Standing in a folder outside the repo I'm trying to compare a folder path to another folder path found inside a git repo in a specific commit.

I'm trying :

git -C "path to repo" diff "commit hash" "folder path in repo" "folder path outside the repo"

This does not work

Can this be done with git diff at all?

Comment: If you want to compare the file in the working tree of your repository with the one outside it then you can use `diff -u` (not `git diff`, just `diff`)

Comment: To compare two files with each other you need `--no-index`. ( `git diff [<options>] --no-index [--] <path> <path>`). Unless you also find a way to somehow specify a revision within file's path, you'll have to checkout/restore the file to the desired revision before comparing it to the out-of-repo file. If you are in bash, you could use git diff in combination with diff to achieve what you want though: `diff <(git show <commit>:<repofile>) <externalfile>`. Sadly `git diff --no-index` can **not** be used instead of `diff` here, because unlike diff, git can't deal with bash's inline file stream.

Comment: @Guildenstern
Thank you for the response. but how can use use the diff -u to compare a file in the git repo that is in an old commit of a specific hash

Comment: @Jay's suggestion is probably better. But (using Bash): `diff -u <(git show <SHA1>:<file in repo>) <file outside repo>`

Comment: @Jay Thank you
I tried the following:
diff (git show 81fd80add58b148e22dd2140643d6a67f5fd1ad8:/frontend/rtl) ./sources/rtl/
This gave an error:  Badly placed ()'s.

Comment: @Meir You need to use `<()`, not `()`.

Comment: What @Guildenstern said. But wait... you are trying to compare folders, not files. My bad. Forget everything I said. My suggestion only works for individual files, not folders. Sorry.